# Calling TableController.Lookup() from one controller on another controller fails

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-mobile-services

In an Azure Mobile App using the .NET backend, I need one controller to look up an entity handled by a second controller.  For example, in the Todo Quickstart project from the Azure team, imagine adding a `UserController` which handles user management.  In `TodoItemController`, I need to call `UserController.GetUser(id)` to check if a user is authorized to post a new TodoItem.

In `TodoItemController.cs`:

```
var userController = new UserController();
var user = userController.GetUser("12345");
if (user.IsAuthorized) 
{
  // Insert TodoItem
}
```

The above code throws an exception when [TableController.Lookup()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn654815.aspx) is called in `UserController.GetUser()`.  The exception says that the request parameter cannot be null.  My guess is that something is missing because I created the `UserController` myself, instead of it being created by the framework.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to work in `TodoItemController.cs`:

```
var context = new todoProjectContext();
var userDomainManager = new EntityDomainManager<User>(context, Request);
var user = userDomainManager.Lookup(id).Queryable.FirstOrDefault();
if (user.isAuthorized)
{
  // Insert item
}
```

Not sure it's the best solution though.